# What does "Place two candles by your side." mean?

Tags: prepositions

> Place two candles by your side.

Does it mean one on either side, and another on another side?

Or does it mean something else?

Comment: I (native speaker) would take it to mean both candles on one side. If they say _"Place two candles by your sides"_ (plural), that would mean one on each side

Comment: It's ambiguous.  If you want to know exactly what is meant, you have to ask for clarification.   Yes, my *best guess* is that it means **one on each side**, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @A.Galloway hrm...no. _"...by your side**s**"_ would be taken to address more than one person's sides. To express placing one candle on each side, we would say something like: _**"Place one candle on either side of you"**_.

Comment: It would be taken to mean that both candles are on the same side.

Comment: I don't see any ambiguity at all. It's the same side. Sounds like the person is lying down.....

Comment: You have mentioned a "full sentence" in a comment on an answer. You must [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/137255/edit) to include the full context, the source, and the exact sentence you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Without further context. it's ambiguous. I'd assume the speaker probably meant to place both on the same side. If he meant two different sides, he'd probably say, "Place one candle on either side of yourself".

Comment: Complete sentence was place two candles on your both sides. But that would mean 4 candles . While in the apparatus there are 2 candles